# Masonry and slideToggle animation with random height

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

**UPDATE :** here is my Jsfiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/Leminence/Lcrowcrd/2/

Hi all, i'm facing some kind of problem with my masonry layout.
Each element of my layout can host some slideToggle content. Thing is, when i toggle down, the element height earn random values and my layout is not updating its placement in real time, but with some latency.

This works, at least, but this behavior is not really esthetic because my element first goes beneath following elements and then, layout is updating.

**I see on masonry site and Desandro codePen that a smooth and immediate update of the layout is possible but only between 2 fix heights. What about random ones ?**

The code is very simple :

```
$('.trigger' ).click(function()
{   
    $('.hiddenContent' ).slideToggle();         
    $('#comments').masonry();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only solution is not to use slideToggle (and the easing with it) but a simple toggle -> no easing, just hide/show method. Masonry is not able to adapt height with easing animation.